# IMB barcode could not be read

Tags: barcode, zxing, barcode-scanner, zxing.net

I have tried to read IMB barcode from an image with the below code snippet, but it always return null. I have also tried with the IMB barcode images in the blackbox testing below, but doesn't work.

https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net/tree/master/Source/test/data/blackbox/imb-1

```
private static void Decode()
{
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(@"\07.png");
    try
    {
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        bitmap.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
        byte[] byteArray = memoryStream.GetBuffer();
        ZXing.LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(byteArray, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
        var binarizer = new HybridBinarizer(source);
        var binBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(binarizer);
        IMBReader imbReader = new IMBReader();

        Result str = imbReader.decode(binBitmap);

    }
    catch { }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by using the below code snippet shared through the below link.
https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net/issues/59

```
private static void Decode2()
{
    var bitmap = new Bitmap(@"\07.png"); // make sure that the file exists at the root level
    try
    {
        var imbReader = new BarcodeReader
        {
            Options =
            {
                PossibleFormats = new List<BarcodeFormat> {BarcodeFormat.IMB}
            }
        };
        var result = imbReader.Decode(bitmap);
        if (result != null)
            System.Console.WriteLine(result.Text);
        else
            System.Console.WriteLine("nothing found");
    }
    catch (System.Exception exc)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(exc.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this code works - thanks for the solution. I have added the reference link in the above update.