# Detect and decode Intelligent Mail Barcode on the image using PHP

Tags: opencv, barcode, barcode-scanner, zbar

Trying to detect and decode the IM barcode on the picture. Using Mac/nix system..Tried many libraries and approaches but have no luck. How to properly do so? I tried to use pyzbar but it couldn't detect Intelligent Mail barcodes. Also tried to use BarBara. And ByteScout - but I was not able to bring it to work (it's Windows thing, using COM - I'm on *nix system). What I want to do - input of picture containing barcode somewhere. Then output - decoded data from the barcode

Comment: If you add information about what you have tried, what was wrong with them, and what your requirements are, it will be easier to get advice and answers.

Comment: I updated my question. Sorry

Comment: Support in Zbar seems difficult. [USPS4CB OneCode Intelligent Mail](https://sourceforge.net/p/zbar/discussion/664596/thread/800c5a59/), [#81 Add support for POSTNET and IMB formats](https://sourceforge.net/p/zbar/feature-requests/81/) ZXing seems to be available on ZXing.Net. How about investigating whether you can transplant it? [IMB barcode could not be read](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47364550/9014308)

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial shows how to read barcode from the image in PHP
Bytescout made numerous amout of pre-made source code pieces for easy usage in your programming tasks. 
It is the barcode decoder with support for code 39, code 128, QR Code, Datamatrix, GS1, PDF417 and all other popular barcodes. Can read barcodes from images, pdf, tiff documents and live web camera. Supports noisy and damaged documents, can split and merge pdf and tiff documents based on barcodes. Can export barcode decoder results to XML, JSON, CSV and into custom data structures. It can help you to read barcode from the image in your PHP application.

You will **save a lot of time on writing and testing code** as you may just take the PHP code from ByteScout BarCode Reader SDK for reading barcode from the image below and use it in your application. This PHP sample code is all you need for your app. Just copy and paste the code, add references (if needs to) and you are all set! Use of **ByteScout BarCode Reader SDK in PHP** is also explained in the documentation included along with the product.

Here is the link : https://bytescout.com/articles/barcode-reader-sdk-php-read-barcode-from-image

Comment: Unfortunately, it couldn't be a solution since it's using COM and php_com_dotnet.dll. I'm a Mac/nix system and I have no access to Windows machines.